# Lampadaire ou Lampe

Tags: vocabulaire

J'essaye de comprendre la différence entre un lampadaire et une lampe. Mes amis français m'ont dit qu'un lampadaire est seulement une lampe extérieure dans la rue. Mais quand je cherche "lampadaire" sur Google, je vois aussi des lampes intérieures. Mes amis ne peuvent pas m'expliquer pourquoi. Pouvez-vous m'aider?

[Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=lampadaire&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD8NvklYDhAhVG1VkKHUVtAuMQ_AUIDigB&biw=1197&bih=635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Définition](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lampe) d'une lampe

> **Étymologie: Du latin lampas (« torche »).**
>   Ustensile fixe ou mobile qui sert à l’éclairage,
>   (Par analogie) Appareil fixe ou mobile au gaz ou muni d’une ou de plusieurs ampoules électriques.

*Photo d'une « torche » :*
[image]

[Définition](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lampadaire) d'un lampadaire

> **Étymologie: Du latin lampadarius (« porte-flambeau »)**.
>   Dispositif permettant l’éclairage des rues la nuit dans une voirie.

*Photo d'un « porte-flambeau » :*
[image]

Si un éclairage est donc par exemple à l'intérieur d'une maison, nous l'appelleront une lampe, en revanche les poteaux servant à éclairer les rues ou voiries seront automatiquement appelées des lampadaires.

L'Étymologie jouant un rôle fort dans la différenciation de ces deux termes dont l'origine est différente malgré une ressemblance au premier regard.

Comment: Lampadaire : Dispositif d'éclairage d'**appartement** ou de la voie publique, à une ou plusieurs lampes, aujourd'hui électriques, montées sur un support élevé (Larousse en ligne).

Comment: Nous utilisons en français lampadaire pour les dispositifs d'éclairage de maisons : https://www.leroymerlin.fr/v3/p/produits/decoration-eclairage/luminaire-interieur/lampadaire-et-liseuse-l1308218701

Comment: Je pense qu'il serait plus juste de définir ces lampes ayant une *"forme lampadaire"* N'oublions pas que les grandes entreprises ont pour but de vendre et faire du profit, non de respecter la langue française.

Comment: : J'ai donné bien des exemples par des dictionnaires respectueux de la langue française ; e.g. TLFi  : B. − Luminaire d'appartement, posé sur le sol et comportant un support vertical de grande dimension et une lampe garnie d'un abat-jour. Il n'était pas quatre heures, mais les stores de macramé et de broderie anglaise l'assombrissait et déjà il avait fallu allumer un lampadaire (Mauriac, Pharis.,1941, p. 271).Au fond [du living-room], à gauche, un canapé, un lampadaire, des appliques (Camus, Requiem,1956, 1repart., 2etabl., p. 827).

Comment: Un *lampadarius* accompagnait les personnalités où qu'elles aillent, à l'extérieur comme à l’intérieur. Il n'y a aucune raison de justifier par l'étymologie une restriction de sens qui n'existe pas. Ce qui est toujours à l'extérieur, c'est un *réverbère* (justement décrit comme *lampadaire extérieur* par Wikipedia). Lampadaire peut parfaitement s'utiliser pour un éclairage intérieur, c'est sa forme qui compte, pas le lieu où il est installé.

Comment: @jlliagre Tous les dictionnaires que j'ai consultés parlent justement de ça. J'ai connu ce sens avant que je n'y aie vu. Du coups, nous utilisons ce mot pour parler exactement de cet appareil "domestique" en Grèce et nous disons que le mot vient du français:-)! Il en de même pour l'adjectif portatif que n'utilisons aussi https://www.leroymerlin.gr/gr/fotistika/epitrapezia-epidapedia/abazour/ . Cependant je me demand pourquoi lampadaire de département pour l'éclairage intérieur n'est pas connu en France.

Comment: @Dimitris Est-ce que vous vouliez dire "lampadaire **d'appartement**" dans votre plus récent commentaire? Je ne trouve nulle part " lampadaire **de département**" (qui risque d'expliquer pourquoi ce terme n'est pas connu en France).

Comment: @PapaPoule : Évidement "lampadaire d'**appartement**" merci bien pour le commentaire (je sais pas à quoi j'ai réfléchi:-)!). Voyez et ma réponse : *Lampadaire : Dispositif d'éclairage d'appartement ou de la voie publique, à une ou plusieurs lampes, aujourd'hui électriques, montées sur un support élevé.* Des revendeurs en parlent aussi.

Comment: @Dimitris Il s'agit d'un aller-retour: le mot grec vient du français mais en remontant son étymologie, on retrouve le grec avec λαμπάς...

Answer (score 4):

ILLUSTRATION

[image]

Des lampes : lampes de chevet, lampes de bureau

[image]

Une lampe de sol : ce n'est ni plus ni moins qu'un mini-lampadaire, ou plutôt un lampadaire au pied très très court.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Un lampadaire de chez Luminaire France : se pose sur le sol des pièces d'habitation, salons, chambres, bureaux ; de la hauteur d'un homme à peu près

---

Les *lampes* et les *lampadaires* font partie des *luminaires* d'une maison ; on trouve aussi dans une maison, comme autres luminaires, les *plafonniers* et les *lustres* ; ces dernies sont accrochés aux plafonds des pièces.

---

[image]

Un lampadaire pour l'extérieur (de style moderne) :  tailles très variable, parfois pas plus haut que la hauteur d'un homme

[image]

Des lampadaires de type courant pour éclairer la voie publique

Comment: Je trouve que ça c'est la bonne réponse. Complète, précise et illustrée. Par contre la mienne n'aborde la lampe et l'autre ne parle pas de lampadaires d'appartement. Est-ce que vous pouvez expliquer pourquoi des locuteurs natifs du français (comme l'indique l'OP) ne connaissent pas l'existence de lampadaires "domestiques" ?

Comment: @Dimitris C'est une bonne illustration, bien que ça pourrait être mieux (je pourrais y ajouter « votre » lampe de sol), mais elle maigre en texte en comparaison. Pourquoi des français ne seraient pas conscient de l'existence du lampadaire d'intérieur est assez surprenant comme si l'on n'en a pas utilisé de toute sa vie, ce qui est possible, on doit en avoir vus chez les autres et en reproductions de toutes sortes (livres, télévision, cinéma). Mais la vie est ainsi faite que parfois des choses évidentes nous échappent.

Comment: Bien que ça pourrait être. Pourquoi pas bien que ça puisse être:-)! Je rigole ! Merci pour le retour. Surprenant "indeed".

Answer (score 4):

Ils ne peuvent l'expliquer parce qu'ils se trompent tout simplement quand ils disent « seulement ». L'analyse de la longueur du pied/mât pour déterminer ce que constituerait techniquement une lampe ou un lampadaire relève de la bagatelle à mon avis, quoiqu'on peut être davantage habitué à utiliser un terme dans un contexte ou un autre (c'est mon cas pour lampadaire à l'extérieur : plus précisément un *réverbère* comme on l'a dit ailleurs). À l'origine au 18<sup>e</sup> le [lampadaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/lampadaire) désigne le « support vertical destiné à soutenir une (ou plusieurs) lampes » (TLFi) ; dès le 19<sup>e</sup> « il se dit aussi d'un luminaire monté sur un haut support ou d'un type de lampe destiné à l'éclairage public, monté sur un tel support » pour éventuellement s'appliquer à une « lampe électrique d'intérieur, à pied » (DHLF). On peut affirmer sans se tromper qu'une lampe de poche n'est pas un lampadaire...

Answer (score 3):

**Lampadaire**

https://translate.google.fr/?hl=fr#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=lampadaire

> Un lampadaire (et non une *lampe de plancher*) éclairerait ce coin de la pièce.
>
> Appareil d'éclairage électrique monté sur un haut support.
>
> Lampadaire de rue (réverbère), d'appartement.

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lampadaire

> B. − Luminaire d'appartement, posé sur le sol et comportant un support
>   vertical de grande dimension et une lampe garnie d'un abat-jour. Il
>   n'était pas quatre heures, mais les stores de macramé et de broderie
>   anglaise l'assombrissait et déjà il avait fallu allumer un lampadaire
>   (Mauriac, Pharis.,1941, p. 271).Au fond [du living-room], à gauche, un
>   canapé, un lampadaire, des appliques (Camus, Requiem,1956, 1repart.,
>   2etabl., p. 827).

Larousse en ligne

> Lampadaire : Dispositif d'éclairage d'appartement ou de la voie
>   publique, à une ou plusieurs lampes, aujourd'hui électriques, montées
>   sur un support élevé.

Le terme même lampadaire s'utilise par des revendeurs très connus en France [1](https://www.leroymerlin.fr/v3/p/produits/decoration-eclairage/luminaire-interieur/lampadaire-et-liseuse-l1308218701) [2](https://www.ikea.com/fr/fr/catalog/categories/departments/lighting/10731/) pour les dispositifs d'éclairage de maisons. Je connais bien cet emploi bien que je ne sois pas locuteur natif du français. Je ne peux pas expliquer pourquoi vos amis ne le connaissent pas.

Comment: @Ced Je ne comprends pas votre édit. C'est l'écriture épicène : http://egalite-diversite.univ-lyon1.fr/files/2013/02/Regles_de_feminisation.pdf

Comment: Il est bien écrit dans le premier paragraphe de votre document *Ne  pas  essayer  de  féminiser  un  texte  écrit  au  masculin,  ça  devient  vite  un véritable casse-tête et ça n'a guère de chance d'être élégant.*
L'écriture inclusive n'a selon moi pas sa place ici.

Comment: @Dimitris Votre phrase d'introduction ne va pas, on comprend l'idée, mais c'est mal dit ; de la part de qqn : [Pour indiquer la pers. qui est à l'origine d'une décision, de qui émane un ordre]. Donc, ce n'est pas ça ; ce que vous essayez de dire c'est que vous ne jugez pas que votre réponse ait toutes les chances d'être aussi fiable, aussi informative que …

Comment: @LPH Je viens de modifier la réponse. Merci.